# WEKA prediction with multiple ARFF files

Tags: r, machine-learning, weka, arff

I'm fairly new to `WEKA` and `ARFF` files and I'm currently working with its `GUI`. Something I'm confused at is how do I do my prediction (classification) with multiple `ARFF` files?

For example, file A has 3 attributes, `"ID"`, `"attribute_1"`, `"attribute_2"` ; while file B has 2 attributes, `"ID"` , `"Scores"` (Main attribute used for prediction).

The problem is, each line of data in `file A` are unique, but the data in `B` are repetitive. Both files are related by their `"ID"`. In other words, `file B` stores a set of `"scores"` for each element at `file A`.

Is there any suggestion on how I could join both `file A` & `B` together? Or is there any way that I could work around `WEKA` to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weka needs one "flattened" table, i.e., `arff`-file. This process is also called denormalization. There’s a weka package (Denormalize) which contains a filter to perform this operation.

There is an example how transactional data can be flattened here: https://weka.wikispaces.com/How+can+I+use+transactional+data+in+Weka%3F

Before using the filter you would have to merge your two files together. If you have `csv`-files or something similar you could achieve this by means of Excel, see for example:

https://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql